# Weird behavior of GDB with roslaunch

Tags: ros, gdb, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to debug a ROS project which is started by the followinng (simplified) launch file. When the launch file is executed with `launch-prefix="gdb --args"` appended to the last part of every node tag, `gdb` seems to start fine. (I also compile the project with `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.)

However, when I try to type `run` command, it's showing a weird behavior, seeeming not getting the correct input that I type (please see at the very last part of the output).

#### project.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="cf_path" default = "..." />
  <arg name="path" default = "..." />

  <node name="feature_tracker" pkg="feature_tracker" type="feature_tracker" output="log" launch-prefix="gdb --args">
    <param name="cf_file" type="string" value="..." />
    <param name="folder" type="string" value="..." />
  </node>

  <node name="estimator" pkg="estimator" type="estimator" output="screen" launch-prefix="gdb --args">
    <param name="cf_file" type="string" value="..." />
    <param name="folder" type="string" value="..." />
  </node>

  <node name="pose_graph" pkg="pose_graph" type="pose_graph" output="screen" launch-prefix="gdb --args">
    ...
  </node>
</launch>
```

#### Output

```
x@laptop:~/project$ roslaunch estimator project.launch
... logging to /home/x/.ros/log/9a2f20e0-0b9d-11ea-be50-380025e3d4b0/roslaunch-laptop-14259.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://laptop:45849/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /feature_tracker/cf_file: /home/x/project...
 * /feature_tracker/folder: /home/x/project...
 * /pose_graph/cf_file: /home/x/project...
 * /pose_graph/skip_cnt: 0
 * /pose_graph/skip_dis: 0.0
 * /pose_graph/visualization_shift_x: 0
 * /pose_graph/visualization_shift_y: 0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /estimator/cf_file: /home/x/project...
 * /estimator/folder: /home/x/project...

NODES
  /
    feature_tracker (feature_tracker/feature_tracker)
    pose_graph (pose_graph/pose_graph)
    estimator (estimator/estimator)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [14269]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 9a2f20e0-0b9d-11ea-be50-380025e3d4b0
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [14282]
started core service [/rosout]
process[feature_tracker-2]: started with pid [14294]
process[estimator-3]: started with pid [14301]
process[pose_graph-4]: started with pid [14303]
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
...
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"
...
...
Reading symbols from /home/x/project/devel/lib/estimator/estimator...GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1
...
...
Reading symbols from /home/x/project/devel/lib/pose_graph/pose_graph...done.
(gdb) done.
(gdb) The program is not being run.
(gdb) The program is not being run.
(gdb) Undefined command: "nnu".  Try "help".
(gdb) Undefined command: "rrnu".  Try "help".
Undefined command: "rrnu".  Try "help".
Undefined command: "nq".  Try "help".
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338103/weird-behavior-of-gdb-with-roslaunch/) by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2019-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be due to conflicting `stdin`/`stdout` muxing/exclusive access.

I typically launch `gdb` in a separate window (from [How to Roslaunch Nodes in Valgrind or GDB](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)):

```
launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-11-20**:
@gvdhoom, This solves the problem. I'm figuring out the equivalent `gnome-terminal` command. Do you happen to know if we could do the same with `gnome-terminal`?

`gnome-terminal --window -e gdb --args` doesn't seem to work. It gives `Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option --args` error when running.

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-11-20**:
Related questions to `gnome-terminal`: https://superuser.com/questions/198015/open-gnome-terminal-programmatically-and-execute-commands-after-bashrc-was-execu

**Comment by [ignite](https://answers.ros.org/users/49351/ignite/) on 2019-11-20**:
Using `gnome-terminal -x bash -c gdb --args`, the debugger `gdb` won't load the symbols correctly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-20**:
Could be a `CWD` issue, but I'm not sure.

**Comment by [rjb0026](https://answers.ros.org/users/35759/rjb0026/) on 2020-03-12**:
@ignite, I'm not sure if you already figured out the issue with gnome-terminal but this launch-prefix worked for me (loaded debug symbols correctly) on Ubuntu 16.04 with a default profile setup:

```
launch-prefix="gnome-terminal -x gdb --args"
```

The `--window-with-profile=<your-profile-name>` option could also be helpful.